# Can we create derived class reference which points to base object

Tags: c#

Can I create a derived class reference which points to base object?

Consider the following example. I am trying this but gives an error.

Why is it not possible?

```
class Shape
{
    public virtual void CalculateArea()
    {
      //Code
    }
}

class Circle: Shape
{
    public override void CalculateArea()
    {
        //Code
    }
}

//Main method
class Main()
{
    Public Static void Main()
    {
        Circle circle = new Shape(); //  WHY THIS IS NOT POSSIBLE
    }
}
```

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Think of it this way - a Circle is a Shape, but a Shape is not necessarily a Circle.

Comment: `overrides` should be `override`, without `s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Circle` is not a base class of `Shape`.

Yo can do this:

```
Shape shape = new Circle();
```

Comment: This concept is called _covariance_, where a more specific type can be used in place of a less specific type, but not the other way around.  This is how variable assignments work in many OOP languages like Java, C#, C++.  The opposite, what @Ravi Solanki was trying, is _contravariance_.  This shows up in other contexts in C#, such as with delegate parameters. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way.
Inheritance is an "is a" relationship e.g.
You can say "A circle **is a** shape", and "every circle **is a** shape"
However, can you say "a shape **is a** circle"? Well, a shape **might** be a circle (straight away we're in trouble, the answer isn't a definite "yes").
Can you say "every shape **is a** circle"? Absolutely no, you cannot. Squares, triangles & rectangles are all shapes, so not all shapes are circles.

In C# you can cast one type to another only if the "**is a**" statement is valid (when in doubt apply the "every x **is a** y" statement for validity).

So in C# the definition `class Circle: Shape` is saying Circle **is a** Shape, and every Circle **is a** Shape.